# ray_cast normals misalignment with respect to face normals

Tags: python, add-on, normals

I'm trying to code an add-on that creates instances of an object on the surface of a target object, having the instances aligned with the normal of the face of the target.

I can't use Geometry Nodes because I want the instance to be placed exactly where I pointed and clicked with the mouse.

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import mathutils as mu
import math

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            region, rv3d = context.region, context.space_data.region_3d
            coord = (event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)

            # Cast a ray from the mouse coordinates
            view_vector = bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
            ray_origin = bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)

            # Use the active view layer's depsgraph
            depsgraph = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

            # Perform ray cast
            result, location, normal, index, object, matrix = context.scene.ray_cast(depsgraph, ray_origin, view_vector, distance=1000.0)

            if result:
                empty: bpy.types.Object
                empty = bpy.data.objects['E']  # The empty to duplicate
                
                bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":True})
                
                obj = bpy.context.active_object
                obj.location = location                  # setting instance location
                obj.rotation_euler = mu.Euler(normal)    # setting instance rotation

        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

It works fine except for the orientation of the instances.

This is the starting situation (I used an empty as object to replicate to clearly show the orientation):
[image]
As you can see, the original empty has no rotation and is placed at the origin.
The target object is made of triangular faces to be sure that faces are planar and avoid ambiguous normal calculations.

The result is here:
[image]
I entered the Edit Mode to make UI show the face normal overlay.

As you can see, face normals and instances on faces are differently oriented.

Maybe I missed something in my code that acts like "Align Euler to Vector" Geometry Node to achieve the goal.
Can you help me?